# click to show content, but only show when all content within has loaded

Tags: jquery

I have the following div container, that is hidden when loading the page, I would like to execute a few things but I'm not sure how.

1) On load the .slideshow container should be hidden and the images should not load.
2) When a user clicks a button the slideshow the images should load and onlyappear but only when they have all loaded.

```
<div class="slideshow" style="display:none">
  <img src="image1.png"/>
  <img src="image2.png"/>
  <img src="image3.png"/>
  <img src="image4.png"/>
  <img src="image5.png"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = $('div.slideshow img'), //caching selectors 
    loaded = 0, //set initial load count = 0
    total_len = $images.length; //total images 
images.load(function() {
    if (++loaded === total_len ) { //match count of loaded to total images
        // All images are loaded code here
    }
});
```

---

Updated after OP's comment

Change your html

```
<div class="slideshow" style="display:none">
  <img src="#" data-src="image1.png"/>
  <img src="#" data-src="image2.png"/>
  <img src="#" data-src="image3.png"/>
  <img src="#" data-src="image4.png"/>
  <img src="#" data-src="image5.png"/>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var div_slideshow = $('div.slideshow')
$('#btnID').click(function () {
    div_slideshow.show();
    div_slideshow.find('img').prop('src', function () {
        return $(this).data('src');
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks but how do I stop all the images loading when first loading the page, and then only load them when the user clicks.